# How to remove multiple selections from a listbox

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

I got this code that put in the variable ativo what is selected in the listbox

```
def selecionado(evt):
   global ativo
   a=evt.widget
   b=a.curselection()
   if len(b) > 0:
       ativo=[a.get(i) for i in a.curselection()]
   else:
       ativo=[]
```

How can i create a function that can delete this, because ativo return this:

```
["Name1\t Code1\n"]
["Name1\t Code1\n", 'Name2\t Code2\n']
```

But if i print the listbox, this shows up

```
.59070320.59070384
```

Even though the listbox is present in my graphic interface with the names and correspodent codes the right way, like:

Name Code

Name Code

So, i have no idea how to delete what is selected, please help me

Comment: you call the delete method of the listbox with an index representing what you want to delete. This is all documented in several places. For example, this is the first response when I google "tkinter listbox delete": http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/listbox.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use yourlistboxname.delete(index)

```
def removeclicked(evt):
w = evt.widget
index = int(w.curselection()[0])
label = w.get(index)
yourlistboxname.delete(index)
```

To bind the evt, add this where you create the widget

```
yourlistboxname.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>',removeclicked)
```

This solution is very easy to find, so maybe I am mistaking your problem. you don't remove the entries in your code, you only get() the entries or change them.
This page should help:

- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm
- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-events-and-bindings.htm

Comment: just a question m8, how should i send evt to the function? i already have one that does that, the first one that i posted, and i can't delete the full function because she has others proposites

Comment: You bind a selection to the listbox
I'll edit it into the code